# How do i find the distance required to resolve a point on a page from a mobile camera?

Tags: optics, resolution, camera-basics, physics

Given all details such as focal length , aperture etc , how can i find the size of a point on a paper that is at a given distance from a mobile camera ? Or vica versa , the distance required to resolve a point of a given size ?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but a point by definition has no size. Can you more exactly describe what you want to know?

Comment: @mattdm I am considering a point from a practical aspect . Take it to be a 10x10 px picture on a laptop screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the farthest a camera can see?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/110315/what-is-the-farthest-a-camera-can-see)

Comment: Since you note in a comment that what you want is the purely-theoretical limit, see the answer about diffraction limits in the previous question linked above.

Answer (score 2):

Experimentally:

- Take a picture of a sheet of ruled/squared paper.
- Open the photo in an image viewed/editor
- Measure the distance in pixels between two lines
- Divide the physical distance (in mm/inches...) between two rules by half that value. This will give you an estimate of the smallest thing you can see in a picture, if the lens is good enough for the sensor.

You can also find [lens test charts on the web](https://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/res-chart.html) that may tell you a bit more about your camera.

Comment: I am more concerned about the theoritical physics behind this measurement

Comment: @PujaDhinchak Then ask in  [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't know this from the technical specs you are thinking of. The resolving power of a camera system depends on the way the lens is built and the properties of the recording medium — and other factors such as lighting and atmosphere.

You may be able to get some details of the recording medium — the sensor — from camera specs, but not enough to be really useful in practice. And for lenses, the resolving power is characterized by testing, not calculated in theory.

Comment: I want to know the physics/calculations behind . Please ignore all practical factors that can affect it . Eg ignore air refractive index , lens quality . Take everything ideal\